# How to use parallelTable to plot a function varing more than one parameter

Tags: parallel-processing, wolfram-mathematica

I want to plot G [a,b,L] fixing a value for b and running 'a' from 15 to 60 and 'L' from 100 to 1000.

```
F[m1_, m_, L_] := ( m m1 EllipticK[-((4 m m1)/(L^2 + (m - m1)^2))])/Sqrt[L^2 + (m - m1)^2];

FA[a_, b_, L_] := NIntegrate[F[m, m1, L], {m, a, b}, {m1, a, m, b}];
FB[a_, b_] := FA[a, b, 0];
S[a_, b_, L_] := 2 (FB[a, b] - FA[a, b, L]);

G[a_, b_, L_] := 1/(\[Pi] (b ^2 - a^2) L) S[a, b, L]
```

I'm doing this in the conventional way with Plot[%] and giving it the values manually. Then I repeat the same but this time fixing 'a' with any value between {a,15,60 } and changing the values of  'b' manually, {b,67,90}.

I'm doing this in the conventional way with Plot[%] and giving it the values manually. Then I repeat the same but this time fixing 'a' with any value between {a,15,60 } and changing the values of 'b' manually, {b,67,90}.

```
Plot[{G[15, 80, L], G[20, 80, L], G[25, 80, L], G[30, 80, L],G[35, 80, L], G[40, 80, L], G[45, 80, L], G[50, 80, L],G[55, 100, L], G[60, 80, L]}, {L, 100, 1000},PlotStyle -> {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dotted}, {Blue,Thick}, {Darker[Green], Thick, Dashing[{0.01, 0.02}]} , {Orange,Thick, Dashed} , {Magenta, Thick,Dotted}, {LightGray}, {Yellow}, {Pink}, {Purple,Dashing[{0.022, 0.02, 0.022, 0.02}]}}, AspectRatio -> 1,Frame -> True, FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[0.002]}]]
```

I have seen people doing this much efficient using ParallelTable but I can't figure it out how. Can you give me a hand?

Comment: The code is incomplete. `F1` is not defined.

Comment: I fixed it now, thanks. F1 was supposed to be FA

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way using `ParallelTable`.

```
styles = {{Black, Thick}, {Red, Dotted}, {Blue, 
   Thick}, {Darker[Green], Thick, Dashing[{0.01, 0.02}]}, {Orange, 
   Thick, Dashed}, {Magenta, Thick, 
   Dotted}, {LightGray}, {Yellow}, {Pink}, {Purple, 
   Dashing[{0.022, 0.02, 0.022, 0.02}]}}

plots = ParallelTable[
   Plot[G[a, b, L], {L, 100, 1000},
    AspectRatio -> 1,
    Frame -> True,
    FrameStyle -> Directive[{Black, Thickness[0.002]}],
    PlotStyle -> styles[[1 + (a - 15)/5]],
    PlotRange -> {{100, 1000}, {0.014, 0.20}},
    PlotLabel -> "b = " <> ToString@b,
    ImageSize -> 500],
   {b, 67, 90, 3}, {a, 15, 60, 5}];

Show @@@ plots // Partition[#, UpTo@2] & // Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

You may have to adjust `PlotRange` individually for each value of `b` to show the full range.